# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() для работы с AFC

Tags: php, wordpress

Делаю фильтр с помощью ACF в WP (последняя версия). Почти работает, но не до конца... Когда захожу в раздел, фильтр появляется и можно нажать на нужный пункт, переходит на него, но появляется ошибка...

Так же при переходе на http://woodbesedka.my/prices/?bedrooms=2, пропадает часть дизайна(меню). И пропадает фильтр и дальнейшее его использование невозможно... Только вернутся назад или в урле править 2 на 3 и т.д.

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Z:\home\woodbesedka.my\www\wp-content\themes\twentyfifteen\category-prices.php on line 29

Функция в **functions.php**

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) 
{

    if( is_admin() ) 
    {       
        return;
    }

    // get meta query
    $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');

    if( isset($_GET['bedrooms']) )
    {
        $bedrooms = explode (' , ', $_GET['bedrooms']);

        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'       => 'bedrooms',
            'value'     => $bedrooms,
            'compare'   => 'IN',
       );
    }

    // update meta query
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);

    return;

}
```

Функция и скрипт в **category-prices.php**:

```
    <?php
        $field = get_field_object('bedrooms');
        $values = explode(' , ', $_GET['bedrooms']);
    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $field['choices'] as $choice_value => $choice_label ): ?>
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $choice_value; ?>" <?php if( in_array($choice_value, $values) ): ?>checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> /> <?php echo $choice_label; ?>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

    (function($) {
        $('#search-houses').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function (){
            //vars
            var $ul = $(this).closest('ul'),
                vals = [];

            $ul.find('input:checked').each(function(){
                vals.push( $(this).val () );
            });

            vals = vals.join(",");
            window.location.replace('<?php echo home_url('prices'); ?>?bedrooms=' +vals);
            console.log ( vals );
        });
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

Делал по примеру - https://vimeo.com/79261102

Comment: `;` после `endforeach` поставьте.

Comment: Поставил, не помогло

Comment: Сделайте `var_dump($field['choices']);` перед циклом `foreach` и смотрите если там массив по которому вы цикл делаете.

Comment: <?php var_dump($field['choices']); echo $choices;?>, добавил, получил вывод Null. Я, если честно, не силен в ПХП. Делал по примеру, в примере работает у меня - нет...

Answer (score 2):

Перед `foreach` добавьте `if(!empty($field['choices'])):`

После `endforeach;` добавьте `endif;`

Comment: Спасибо! Ошибка(Warning) пропала... Осталась вторая проблемка, может поможете?

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` можно проводить только с итерируемыми объектами (например, массив). `null`, `false` туда не входят. Так что либо приводите переменную принудительно к массиву, либо проверяйте является ли переменная массивом `is_array()`.